# Difference in constructor function definition

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

I would like to know if there is some hidden difference between the two following constructor function:

```
var Person = function(name){
     this.say=function(){
         console.log(name);
     }
}
```

and this one:

```
function Person(name){
         this.say=function(){
             console.log(name);
         }
  }
```

suppose we are always going to write:

```
var x = new Person('xxxxx');
x.say();
```

It appear to be the same in order to me, but I'm really green in javascript and I would like to know if some form is wrong and if there is some best practices to follow.

Comment: The difference is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/336868#336868

Comment: I think this may be the third time today this has been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference as far as constructors are concerned. All functions in JavaScript can be called as constructors (whether they throw errors or not is a different issue altogether).

The difference is between how the functions are declared.

The first declaration is as a variable that requires execution. The second declaration is as a function that is hoisted.

`var foo` and `function foo` statements in JavaScript get hoisted to the top of their closing scope (nearest `function` parent). This means that:

```
(function () { //closure for scope
  doStuff();
  var foo = bar;
}());
```

is actually:

```
(function () {
  var foo;
  doStuff();
  foo = bar;
}());
```

functions react similarly:

```
(function () {
  doStuff();
  function foo() {
    bar = baz;
  }
}());
```

is the same as:

```
(function () {
  function foo() {
    bar = baz;
  }
  doStuff();
}());
```

This distinction is important because a function declared in a variable isn't accessible until after it's been declared:

```
(function () {
  foo(); //this doesn't work and will result in an error
  var foo = function () {
    alert('works');
  };
}());
```

whereas a function is accessible as long as it's somewhere within scope:

```
(function () {
  foo(); //works!
  function foo() {
    alert('works!');
  }
}());
```